# Ideals of $R/N$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, ideals

I have a proof in a book I'm reading that says (we are dealing with ring $R$ and ideal $N$) that the ideals of $R/N$ are of the form $M/N$ where $M$ is an ideal of $R$ that contains $N$. Can someone explain this to me please.

Comment: I fixed the notation. To answer the question: take an ideal in the quotient, and take its preimage by the quotient map $R \rightarrow R/N$. What do you get?

Comment: You get an Ideal in R. But I don't see what this shows (I'm sorry I am new to this).

Comment: "You get an ideal in R." Right! And that's exactly what you were looking for --- an ideal $M$ in $R$.

Comment: So if we call that ideal $M$. How does that show that all the ideals are of the form $M/N$ and that $N$ is in $M$?

Answer (score 2):

An ideal of $R/N$ is the kernel of a ring homomorphism $R/N\to A$. Combined with the canonical map $R\to R/N$ we obtain an ideal $M$ as kernel of a homomorphism $R\to A$. Verify that $M/N$ is the original ideal in $R/N$.

Comment: How can I go about verifying that Hagen von Eitzen ?

Answer (score 0):

If $a,b\in M$ then $a+N$ and $b+N$ are elements of $M/N$.

Note that $(a+N)+(b+N)=a+b+N\in M/N$ since $a+b\in M$.

Secondly note that $(r+N)(a+N)=ra+N\in M/N$ for any $r\in R$ since $ra\in M$.

Also $(a+N)(r+N)=ar+N\in M/N$.

This together shows that $M/N$ is a (two-sided) ideal or ring $R/N$.

Conversely let $K$ be some ideal of ring $R/N$. It is to be shown that an ideal $M$ of ring $R$ exists such that $K=M/N$. You can take $M:=\{a\in R\mid a+N\in K\}$ for that.

Answer (score 0):

Put $S=R/N$ and let $K$ be an ideal of $S$. Then one has the canonical morphism $S\overset{\pi_2}\to S/K$, which can be composed with the canonical morphism $R\overset{\pi_1}\to R/N$:
$$
  R\overset{\pi_1}\to R/N=S\overset{\pi_2}\to S/K.
$$
Calling $f:R\to S/K$ the composite morphism it is clear that $M=\ker(f)$ is an ideal of$~R$. Now $r\in M\iff \pi_1(r)\in\ker(\pi_2)=K$, and since $\pi_1$ is surjective one has $K=\pi_1(M)$. But $\pi_1$ is taking classes modulo$~N$, so a natural notation for $\pi_1(M)$ is $M/N$, so $K=M/N$. And it is clear that $\ker(f)\supseteq\ker(\pi_1)$, in other words that $M\supseteq N$.